# One word for "to be upset"

Tags: word-request

Is there a one word (intransitive verb) for the phrase "to be upset"?

- I will be upset
- I will ___? (cry?)

When my son doesn't want to do something I usually say, "You upset me", but I want to have another option that expresses sorrow and disappointment together.

Comment: Have you checked synonyms of upset? https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/upset

Comment: Is it strictly necessary that what you're looking for be a one-word phrase?  What's wrong with a longer expression that's more idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when the word *upset* is used we default to thinking of anger. Single words used to express behaviour related to anger include *fume, rage, storm, rant, and rave*.

However, you mention in a comment to the question that by *upset* you actually mean a combination of sorrow and disappointment.

*Cry* is certainly behaviour that could be expressed by somebody feeling sorrow and disappointment—but since you aren't using it, it seems you are looking for something else.

---

I could list a long series of synonyms here, but you are talking about your son not doing something you want him to do. If you are feeling "sorrow and disappointment," it's probably because you fear for the consequences of his *not* doing what you've asked him to do.

Based on this, I would say:

> I will **worry**.

This is a subtle consequence to express to a child, as it describes something internal rather than observable behaviour. But based on his empathy and intuition (and if he's old enough to understand it) it might be a more honest communication.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that in many ways:

> You perturb me.
>
> You frazzle me.
>
> You distemper me.
>
> You distress me.
>
> You disturb me.

Answer (score 0):

Upset is a common word and you are actually asking for a *synonym*. Well, there are many; google it and you get it. However, another word that I may prefer is ....

> I will be sad

I considered that you have a son who's quite young. So, *sad* should be a simple word and should convey the message straightforwardly. Indeed, a son may stop doing things that make his dad *sad.*

Comment: It is still as long as "I'll be upset". I mean something like "I will cry" but instead of cry use another word that is a synonym of "be upset".

Comment: @SovereignSun now you changed the question! It's not *crying* like... I think you should be clear in asking up there.

Comment: But he asked for a one-word replacement and you gave him two words that don't even mean the same thing.